# Displaying looped array items individually in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

It's a todo list. The user is making one by entering an item, then pressing enter.  I would like the enter item to display right after the enter key is pressed but whats actually happening is that all the (li) tags are being displayed simultaneously with the current entered key.

```
 <body>
    <h1>Create your todo list</h1>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Text Here" id="inputField">
      <ul>
        <li id="item-one"></li>
        <li id="item-two"></li>
        <li id="item-three"></li>
        <li id="item-four"></li>
        <li id="item-five"></li>
        <li id="item-six"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="todo-list.js"></script>
  </body>


//Using an external file

var textField = document.querySelector("#inputField");
var lists = document.querySelectorAll("li");

textField.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {

  for(let i = 0; i < lists.length; i++){
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      lists[i].style.visibility = "visible";
      lists[i].style.fontSize = "16px";
      lists[i].textContent = textField.value;
    }
  }
});


//I have also tried this. The results were the same.

function itemsEntered() {
  for(let i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
    lists[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    lists[i].style.fontSize = "16px";
    lists[i].textContent = textField.value;
  }
}

textField.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  if(e.key === "Enter") {
    itemsEntered();
  }
});
```

Each user input to be store in an (li) tag and displayed individually.

Comment: This doesn't look like java to me.  Are you sure you didn't mean to tag this question as javascript?

Comment: Question tags corrected: [tag:java] removed, [tag:javascript] added. No sense attracting the wrong experts to the question

Comment: This is JavaScript.  Different than Java.  But your code is looping through all items in the list.  You need another if statement checking if the visibility is already set to true, if so, do nothing if it is not, then set to true and break out of the loop

Comment: Sorry, it was really a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(let i = 0; i < lists.length; i++){
if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    if(lists[i].style.visibility == "visible") {
        continue;
    }
    lists[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    lists[i].style.fontSize = "16px";
    lists[i].textContent = textField.value;
    break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This just tracks the current item with a counter so there's no need to loop through everything every time.  It's very basic of course.

```js
        var textField = document.querySelector("#inputField");
        var lists = document.querySelectorAll("li");
        var counter = 0;
        textField.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
                if (e.key === 'Enter' && counter < 6) {
                    lists[counter].textContent = textField.value;
                    textField.value = "";
                    counter++;
                }
        });
```

```html
    <h1>Create your todo list</h1>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Text Here" id="inputField">
        <ul>
            <li id="item-one"></li>
            <li id="item-two"></li>
            <li id="item-three"></li>
            <li id="item-four"></li>
            <li id="item-five"></li>
            <li id="item-six"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```